# Need help to create an XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML file which was generated from a SQL table. And I need to transform the XML into my desired output XML.

Input XML:

```
<rowset>
<row>
<aaa>123</aaa>
<bbb>James</bbb>
<ddd>Large</ddd>
<eee>Black</eee>
<ddd>456213</ddd>
</row>
<row>
<aaa>123</aaa>
<bbb>James</bbb>
<ddd>Large</ddd>
<eee>Blue</eee>
<ddd>456213</ddd>
</row>
<row>
<aaa>123</aaa>
<bbb>James</bbb>
<ddd>small</ddd>
<eee>Black</eee>
<ddd>456213</ddd>
</row>
<row>
<aaa>123</aaa>
<bbb>James</bbb>
<ddd>small</ddd>
<eee>blue</eee>
<ddd>456213</ddd>
</row>
<row>
<aaa>321</aaa>
<bbb>William</bbb>
<ddd>Large</ddd>
<eee>White</eee>
<ddd>555555</ddd>
</row>
<row>
<aaa>321</aaa>
<bbb>William</bbb>
<ddd>Large</ddd>
<eee>Yellow</eee>
<ddd>555555</ddd>
</row>
<row>
<aaa>321</aaa>
<bbb>William</bbb>
<ddd>small</ddd>
<eee>White</eee>
<ddd>555555</ddd>
</row>
<row>
<aaa>321</aaa>
<bbb>William</bbb>
<ddd>small</ddd>
<eee>Yellow</eee>
<ddd>555555</ddd>
</row>
</rowset>
```

Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tXML xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts">
<product product-id = "123">
    <Name>James</Name>
    <Image>
        <Image image-view-type = "Large" image-color = "Black">
        <Image image-view-type = "Large" image-color = "Blue">
        <Image image-view-type = "small" image-color = "Black">
        <Image image-view-type = "small" image-color = "Blue">
    </Image>
    <DeptCode>456213</DeptCode>
</product>
<product product-id = "321">
    <Name>William</Name>
    <Image>
        <Image image-view-type = "Large" image-color = "White">
        <Image image-view-type = "Large" image-color = "Yellow">
        <Image image-view-type = "small" image-color = "White">
        <Image image-view-type = "small" image-color = "Yellow">
    </Image>
    <DeptCode>555555</DeptCode>
</product>
</tXML>
```

How to write XSLT for this.
Please note Products are many. so there will be thousands of products.

Comment: Which version of XSLT are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort this XML, you can use Muenchian Grouping. Following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:key name="prodId" match="row" use="aaa" />
  <xsl:template match="rowset">
    <xsl:for-each select="row[generate-id() =
            generate-id(key('prodId', aaa)[1])]"> 
      <product product-id = "{aaa}">
        <Name><xsl:value-of select="bbb"/></Name> 
        <xsl:for-each select="key('prodId', aaa)">
          <Image>
            <xsl:attribute name="image-view-type" select="ddd[1]"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="image-color" select="eee"/>
          </Image>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <DeptCode><xsl:value-of select="ddd[2]"/></DeptCode>
      </product>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input XML produces the output

```
<product product-id="123">
  <Name>James</Name>
  <Image image-view-type="Large" image-color="Black"/>
  <Image image-view-type="Large" image-color="Blue"/>
  <Image image-view-type="small" image-color="Black"/>
  <Image image-view-type="small" image-color="blue"/>
  <DeptCode>456213</DeptCode>
</product>
<product product-id="321">
  <Name>William</Name>
  <Image image-view-type="Large" image-color="White"/>
  <Image image-view-type="Large" image-color="Yellow"/>
  <Image image-view-type="small" image-color="White"/>
  <Image image-view-type="small" image-color="Yellow"/>
 <DeptCode>555555</DeptCode>
</product>
```

As short explanation: First define a key for sorting

```
<xsl:key name="prodId" match="row" use="aaa" />
```

and then select all rows with the same value for this key:

```
<xsl:for-each select="row[generate-id() =
        generate-id(key('prodId', aaa)[1])]">
```

These are two rows with the unique values for `aaa`.
Then iterate over all rows in the rowset that have the same value for `aaa` as the current unique prodId:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('prodId', aaa)">
```

Muenchian Grouping is described in detail in this article by Jeni Tennison http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml

As additional reference for XSLT grouping you can have a look at http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N4486.html

Comment: **1** This is an incorrect (incomplete) implementation of Muenchian grouping. Instead of `<xsl:for-each select="//row[aaa=$currentProductId]">` you should be using `<xsl:for-each select="key('prodId', aaa)">`. This is both simpler and more efficient (and does not require a variable).  ---- **2.** You are assuming the OP uses XSLT 1.0. If they do, then this `<xsl:attribute name="image-view-type" select="ddd[1]"/>` will not work for them.

Comment: @michael.hor257k For issue 2 - depends on the xslt processor, 'works' e.g. with Saxon 9.5.1.6, but not with 6.5.5. In general it's a bad idea to use the same node name for different items (and it's possible that the real input xml has unique node names instead and this is a copy/paste error in the example xml). Thanks for mentioning, tend to forget about some 1.0 restrictions because of having worked with 2.0 for too long.

Comment: "*depends on the xslt processor*" No, it depends on the XSLT version. In XSLT 1.0, `select` is not a valid attribute of `<xsl:attribute>`. In XSLT 2.0, you don't need Muenchian grouping.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks for pointing this out, I tried to include a shortened version of a certain doubt towards the proc. issue by having 'works' (with sax 9.5) in prev. comment in quotation marks. It's just that http://xsltransform.net/94hvTz4 'works' though declared as 1.0. About 2.0, yes, then e.g. `xsl:for-each-group` etc would be better to use.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
  <xsl:key name="data" match="row" use="bbb"/>
  <xsl:output method = "xml" omit-xml-declaration = "no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <root>
      <xsl:for-each select="row[count(. | key('data', bbb)[1]) = 1]">
        <product>
          <xsl:attribute name="product-id">
            <xsl:value-of select="aaa"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <Name>
            <xsl:value-of select="bbb"/>
          </Name>
          <Image>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('data',bbb)">
              <Image>
                <xsl:attribute name="image-view-type">
                  <xsl:value-of select="ddd"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="image-color">
                  <xsl:value-of select="eee"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
              </Image>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </Image>
          <DeptCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="ddd[string(number(.)) != 'NaN']"/>
          </DeptCode>
        </product>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
```